# Insert Chinese Character String into MySQL LongBlob column as UTF-8

Tags: java, mysql

By doing this:

```
File file1 = new File("/usr/local/test/multipartMimeMsg.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(file1);
            String s = byteArrayToHexString(multipartMimeMsg.getBytes());
            fos1.write(s.getBytes(), 0, s.getBytes().length);
```

I verified that my multipartMimeMsg string can see the hexa representation of the chinese characters. I then proceed to do this:

```
prepstmt.setObject(2, multipartMimeMsg );
```

But it turns up as ??? or 3F3F3F in hexa representation. It should show E4BDA0E5A5BDE59097 Am I missing something? I have set my Table Options to Charset utf8, Collation to utf8_general_ci.

Connection string is  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `setObject()` can handle LOBs correctly - have you tried this with `setBytes()` or `setBinaryStream()`?

Also, any reason why you're storing text as a `BLOB` instead of `TEXT`?

Comment: It contains binary data because of media like png, jpeg etc, ok so far i added  ?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8 to the back of my connection string, seems to be working. Need to verify it.

Comment: I see, I was assuming that `multipartMimeMsg` is a String.

Comment: multipartMimeMsg is a String converted from bytes.

Comment: Then I'm confused again.  If `multipartMimeMsg` is a String, why store it in a `BLOB`? The underlying data may be binary, but it's MIME encoded, right? When you say converted from bytes, where do those bytes originally come from?

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = byteArrayToHexString(multipartMimeMsg.getBytes());
```

I assume multipartMimeMsg is a string. Look carefully about the getBytes() method in JavaDoc, it will use system default character set(depending on your OS) to encode the string into bytes, which can vary on different systems.

The more accurate way is set the exact character set you want, like aString.getBytes("UTF-8").

And for the column definition problem, I recommend using "TEXT" type, as suggested by @Dmitri.